# Mapbox Static Images API tile positioning for perfect edges

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm working on a Python project that builds large hi-res images using tiles retrieved from the Mapbox static images API using customized styles designed in Mapbox studio.
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/
(updated with correct link)

At the moment I have a proof of concept that works well at z15.5 but it won't work at other zoom levels without a good bit of work. I'm thinking there's a better/proper/elegant way to handle tile positioning.

Any suggestions on how to calculate the lat/lon for a second tile that aligns seamlessly with the first one?  Longitude is easy enough, since the difference in distance between tiles stays the same every time.  It's latitude that has the fun factor, since it changes for each tile.

I've tried using QGIS to export a large image but it didn't perform very well and pummeled the API usage.

Comment: Why would you want to have lat/lon coordinates for the next tile? Just place right next to the previous one.

Comment: Sorry, That's a great question given the link I pasted.  I've corrected the post to the API currently in use.

Comment: If you use `bbox` option when retrieving static image, then that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The 'bbox' option works great if you want I large region in a 1280px file.  In a sense I'm looking for a way to cover the same area you could fit in a 'bbox' , covering a large area, but at a higher zoom level for detail resulting in a very large 10,000px or larger image.   The challenge is that the distance between requests changes as you go away from the Equator.  So, for example, a request at the Equator would be followed by a request 1 mile away. On the other hand, a request at a latitude of 45 is followed by a request 0.75 miles away.

Comment: usually its not adviced to use fractional zoom level values, as they are usually rounded off (the API documentation mentions it). Also putting some screeshots of the problem with your output will help.

Comment: Also I am assuming that this returns a static image constructed by overlaying basemap with some vector data loaded in mapbox studio, which means you are getting images that follows a mercator projection. I would suggest to follow a mercator tiling scheme using https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile to create grid and fetch images using the bbox constructed for each tile in the grid

Comment: @Abhilshit,  Yep that's basically it.  The request sends back a PNG rendering of the style designed in studio. I was thinking there would be something that worked with the projection in use.  I'll check out the mercantile route for a grid.
I'm aiming to stay within the bounds for the two decimal rounding for the zoom level so there should be an issue.

Comment: Just an idea: Have you thought about actually using tile layer for your purpose. Here you would just have to calculate the right `x`, `y` and `z` values for pieces of your final image. You would then have no problems with stitching those tiles.

Comment: @TomazicM using the grid is certainly part of the solution. 
Since I'm generating a very large image I've been looking to see how this can be done in larger pieces.

Comment: The solution turns out to be the difference in degrees from one x y z tile to the next multiplied by the result of dividing the requested image size /by 512.  This gives me the difference in degrees to use for a static images request scaled to the new pixel size.
I'm testing this further but seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using [Mercantile](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile) I got a better understanding of navigating the map grid.  In the end I'm not using it in my project but it was a good hands on learning tool.

Basically, the step to the next tile needs to be scaled. This is because the static images API can return larger images that cover larger areas than the usual 512px grid tile.  This turns out to be very simple.  Instead of just going to the next tile over on the grid you need to go to the position that is `requested_image_size / 512` away.  So, a 1024px static images response will join seamlessly with one that is 2 grid tiles away, or 2.5 for a 1280px image.

I'm using this to generate images that are used for print so I'm not aiming for a fast web app.  The standard grid tiles are perfect for interactive stuff. For my purposes this approach results in a faster final image.

Performance notes for a final image that's 10240px square:

- 64  requests for 1280px images: 79 seconds to complete
- 100 requests for 1024px images: 103 seconds to complete
- 400 requests for 512px images:  208 seconds to complete

This only works starting at z11 for 1024px images and z12 for 1280px.  The grid needs enough tiles to accommodate larger sizes.  Zoom levels below these thresholds will not join seamlessly.

Zoom levels below z11 need to be done with 512px tiles so I also have things setup to use the Static Tiles API for this scenario and maintain API usage cost efficiency at that tile size.